# How to extend linear regression in no data zone

Tags: matlab

I have this script:

```
scatter(X,Y)
p = polyfit(X,Y,1);
FX= polyval(p,X);
hold on
plot(X,FX)
```

which for the actual data `XY` gives me this chart:

[image]

In the chart you see the hidden line in blu that I traced manually on the picture. Normally I do this in excel adding an additional X point but obviously this does not work in Matlab. How can I obtain such extension in Matlab?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do the same thing: append a new value to `X` and regenerate `FX` using polyval

```
newX = [X; 140];
newFX = polyval(p, newX);
plot(newX, newFX);
```

this will work if X is a column vector. If it's a row vector then append horizontally using `[X 140]` instead.

Comment: First in first served. Thanks a lot I will accept this answer.

Comment: By the skin of my teeth : ) My pleasure.

Answer (score 3):

Like in excell you need to add `X` points.
Here's an example:

```
scatter(X,Y); 
p = polyfit(X,Y,1); %// estimating the line paramters
```

Now all you need is use different `X` values ( suppose `maxX=140` ):

```
plotX = linspace( min(X), maxX, 100 );
FX= polyval(p,plotX);
plot( plotX, FX );
```